# How to set alias for python3 on OSX

Tags: macos, terminal, python, path, alias

I'm trying to set an alias for `python3` so I can run it with `python`.

Here's my current `.bash_profile`

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
alias python=“python3”
alias 3=“python3”
alias py=“python3”
```

When I run `python` I get `-bash: “python3”: command not found`.

I can run `python3` and it will correctly open `py 3.X.X` (`3.6.1` at time of posting).

There are plenty of half-answers over the years on here & SO, and a few comments mentioning my issue, but hopefully this can be a resource for a complete answer. Or maybe one of you is better at googling than I am and it can be a duplicate question!

Comment: You shouldn't correct the code in the question as it will confuse future readers. I've rolled back the changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### When I run `python` I get `-bash: “python3”: command not found`

Why are you using `“` and `”` (smart quotes) instead of `'` (normal single quotes)?

Try the following (corrected) `.bash_profile`

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
alias python='python3'
alias 3='python3'
alias py='python3'
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Bash command line for Linux](http://ss64.com/bash/) -  An excellent reference for all things Bash command line related.
- [alias](http://ss64.com/bash/alias.html) - Create an alias, aliases allow a string to be substituted for a word when it is used as the first word of a simple command.

Comment: Thanks, I saw your comment and fixed the issue. Marked as correct answer. Stupid case of using `open` after not seeing results using `nano` (because I didn't open a new instance)